# SimpleXMLElement() - XPath() & SOAP returning nothing

Tags: php, xml, soap, simplexml

After hours of searching, finding similar threads and still not being able to get it to work I've resorted to posting my specific problem. I'm getting a SOAP encoded XML response from a server that i want to use SimpleXMLElement() on, but i'm having a real hard time establishing a base path to work from.

I've tried two different methods:

**xpath():**

```
public function XMLParseUserData($xml)
{
    $ActivityData = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);

    $ActivityData->registerXPathNamespace("ns", "http://webservices.website.net/");
    $basePath = $ActivityData->xpath('//ns:GetUserActivityDataResult/ActArray');

    foreach ($basePath->ACT as $userActivity)
    {
        $this->uGUID = $userActivity->UserGUID;
        echo $this->uGUID."<br />";
    }
}
```

**children():**

```
public function XMLParseUserData($xml)
{
    $ActivityData = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);

    $basePath = $ActivityData->children('soap',true)->Body->GetUserActivityDataResponse->GetUserActivityDataResult->ActArray->ACT;

    foreach ($basePath as $userActivity)
    {
        $this->uGUID = $userActivity->UserGUID;
        echo $this->uGUID."<br />";
    }
}
```

**The XML response:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <soap:Body>
            <GetUserActivityDataResponse xmlns="http://webservices.website.net/">
                <GetUserActivityDataResult>
                    <ResponseCode>SUCCESS</ResponseCode>
                    <FailedUserCount>0</FailedUserCount>
                    <ActCount>1</ActCount>
                    <ActArray>
                        <ACT>
                            <UserGUID>0dc299ba-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-7ca097d51eb6</UserGUID>
                            <ActDataCount>15</ActDataCount>
                            <ActData>
                                <ACT_DATA>
                                    <Start>2012-03-05T08:40:00</Start>
                                    <End>2012-03-05T09:00:00</End>
                                    <SourceCount>1</SourceCount>
                                    <SourceData>
                                        <ACT_SRC_DATA>
                                            <Source>ACTIPED</Source>
                                            <TypeCount>3</TypeCount>
                                            <TypeData>
                                                <ACT_TYPE_DATA>
                                                    <Type>WALK</Type>
                                                    <S>40</S>
                                                    <C>2</C>
                                                    <D>20</D>
                                                    <T>16</T>
                                                </ACT_TYPE_DATA>
                                                <ACT_TYPE_DATA>
                                                    <Type>RUN</Type>
                                                    <S>20</S>
                                                    <C>2</C>
                                                    <D>20</D>
                                                    <T>10</T>
                                                </ACT_TYPE_DATA>
                                                <ACT_TYPE_DATA>
                                                    <Type>OTHER</Type>
                                                    <S>0</S>
                                                    <C>0</C>
                                                    <D>0</D>
                                                    <T>28</T>
                                                </ACT_TYPE_DATA>
                                            </TypeData>
                                            <MetricCount>0</MetricCount>
                                        </ACT_SRC_DATA>
                                    </SourceData>
                                </ACT_DATA>
                               </ActData>
                            </ACT>
                        </ActArray>
                        <AsOfServerTimeGMT>2012-03-06T16:41:41.513</AsOfServerTimeGMT>
                    </GetUserActivityDataResult>
                </GetUserActivityDataResponse>
            </soap:Body>
        </soap:Envelope>
```

Neither method works and both leave me with the same error:

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /c08/domains/dev.mysite.com/html/class/XMLParse.class.php on line 29
```

Comment: [I get *lots* more errors](http://codepad.org/z4tT7INz) for that XML. It's invalid and cannot be parsed as XML.

Comment: My bad. The response was massive +100 more <ACT> tags so i shortened it for display purposes and accidentally cut of the closing </ActData> tag. Post edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It says:

```
<GetUserActivityDataResponse xmlns="http://webservices.website.net/">
```

and you are trying to do

```
$basePath = $soapEnvelope
    ->children('soap', true)
    ->Body
    ->GetUserActivityDataResponse
    …
```

which means you try to get `<soap:GetUserActivityDataResponse>` which obviously doesnt exist. You have to  do ([demo](http://codepad.org/7HTenODb))

```
$basePath = $soapEnvelope
    ->children('soap', true)
    ->Body
    ->children('http://webservices.website.net/')
    ->GetUserActivityDataResponse
    ->GetUserActivityDataResult
    ->ActArray
    ->ACT;
```

Actually, you could just do `->children()` to jump back to the default namespace, but I find providing the namespace explicitly somewhat clearer. Your choice.

Your XPath fails because you didn't specify the namespace for `ActArray`. Also, when `xpath()` is successful, it returns an array of SimpleXmlElements. You tried `array->ACT`, which doesn't work because an array is not an object. The first `ActArray` is in `$basePath[0]`. So you have to adjust the code to

```
$basePath = $soapEnvelope->xpath('//ns:GetUserActivityDataResult/ns:ActArray');
foreach ($basePath[0]->ACT as $userActivity) {
…
```

To get the ACT elements directly, change the XPath to

```
//ns:GetUserActivityDataResult/ns:ActArray/ns:ACT
```

Comment: Ahhh I see. Wasn't far off! Excellent, thanks very much Gordon!